# Problema para cambiar el título de una ventana emergente

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy utilizando la libreria Tkinter para configurar un sistema de recordatorios, en el que le pongo un título y lo describo. Mi intención era que cuando le diesemos al boton "New Reminder".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saliese una ventana emergente que tuviese como título el que nosotros le hayamos puesto, en este caso "Recordatorio miércoles.
El problema es que el título de esta ventana emergente es igual que el de la primera ventana emergente.
Con la opción `notewin.title("Recordatorio miércoles")` he conseguido cambiar el título pero no automatiza el proceso.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a descubrir cómo conseguir que la ventana emergente, una vez pulsado en New Reminder!, sea el mismo que el que hemos insertado?

A continuación os dejo el código completo.

```
  import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

def addReminder(text,x,y,notes,reminders,entry):
    notewin = tkinter.Toplevel()
    notewin.title(entry)
    notewin.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    notewin.geometry("+"+str(x)+"+"+str(y))
    
    reminder = tkinter.Text(notewin,bg="yellow", width=30,height=15)

    reminder.insert(tkinter.END,text)
    
    reminder.pack()

    
    notes.append(notewin)
    reminders.append(reminder)
    
    
    def deleteWindowHandler():
        print("Window Deleted")
        notewin.withdraw()
        notes.remove(notewin)
        reminders.remove(reminder)
    
    notewin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", deleteWindowHandler)
    
    
def main():
    
    def post():
        print("Post")
        addReminder(note.get("1.0",tkinter.END), root.winfo_rootx()+5,root.winfo_rooty()+5,notes,reminders,entry)
        note.delete("1.0",tkinter.END)               
   
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    
    root.title("Reminder!")
    root.resizable(width=False,height=False)

    notes = []
    reminders = []

    bar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    
    fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(bar,tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.quit)
    bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fileMenu)
    root.config(menu=bar)
    
    mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(root,borderwidth=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    mainFrame.pack()
    
    note = tkinter.Text(mainFrame,bg="yellow", width=30,height=15)
    note.pack()
    
    tkinter.Button(mainFrame,text="New Reminder!", command=post).pack()
    
    #Code for the Entry and Text widgets in this application
    titleFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainFrame)
    titleFrame.pack()
    
    noteTitle = tkinter.StringVar()
    titleLabel = tkinter . Label ( titleFrame , text =" Title :")
    titleLabel . grid ( row =1 , column =1 , sticky = tkinter . E)
    titleText = tkinter . Entry ( titleFrame , textvariable = noteTitle )
    titleText . grid ( row =1 , column =2 , columnspan =2 , sticky = tkinter . E+ tkinter . W)
    entry = noteTitle.get()
        
  
    try:
        print("reading reminders.txt file")
        file = open("reminders.txt","r")
        x = int(file.readline())
        y = int(file.readline())
        root.geometry("+"+str(x)+"+"+str(y))
        
        
        line = file.readline()
        while line.strip() != "":
            x = int(line)
            y = int(file.readline())
            text = ""
            line = file.readline()
            while line.strip() != "____....____._._._":
                text = text + line
                line = file.readline()
                
            text = text.strip()
            
            addReminder(text,x,y,notes,reminders,entry)
            
            line = file.readline()
    except:
        print("reminders.txt not found")
        
        
    
    def appClosing():
        print("Application Closing")
        file = open("reminders.txt","w")
        
        file.write(str(root.winfo_x())+"\n")
        file.write(str(root.winfo_y())+"\n")
        
        for i in range(len(notes)):
            print(notes[i].winfo_rootx())
            print(notes[i].winfo_rooty())
            print(reminders[i].get("1.0",tkinter.END))
            
            file.write(str(notes[i].winfo_rootx())+"\n")
            file.write(str(notes[i].winfo_rooty())+"\n")
            file.write(reminders[i].get("1.0",tkinter.END)+"\n")
            file.write("____....____._._._\n")
            
        file.close()
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
        sys.exit()
        
    
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", appClosing)  
    
         
    tkinter.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Has que la función addRemainder acepte un argumento más, que sería el titulo de la ventana. El resto es obtener el contenido del entry y pasarselo como argumento a addRemainder

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias pero sigue sin funcionar. He insertado una línea `entry = noteTitle.get()` para obtener el texto que introducimos en el recuadro blanco y la variable entry la he metido como nuevo parámetro en la función addReminder. Dentro de la función addReminder he insertado la línea `notewin.title(entry)`. Pero despues de todo esto sigue sin funcionar. Acabo de cambiar el código en la publicación al nuevo. ¿Podrías echarle un vistazo y decirme donde tengo que modificar algo para que funcione? Gracias